# How do I get the file id back from gridform?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, gridfs-stream

For reference you can check the [issue I submitted on GitHub](https://github.com/aheckmann/gridform/issues/10). I am able to stream to MongoDB and the file is persisted and accessible, but the README shows during the parsing you can access the file id. This is required if you want to log or enqueue background jobs for the file. I am unable to log the file id, but logging the file object shows id is either undefined or null depending on the callback.

Comment: Did you associate the gridform to the mongodb... `gridform.mongo = mongo;`?

Comment: Yes, though in my case I am currently using mongoskin  `var mongo = require('mongoskin'); gridform.db = db; gridform.mongo = mongo; ` Also, remember the file is stored and accessible from the command line after the request completes, I just can't get the file id during the formidable/gridform form parsing